# Data scraping the page JUST written with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that's written with PHP, and after the PHP writes it, I want be able to search through the HTML source code to find certain tags. Is this impossible/unwise?

I tried using file_get_contents at the end of the script when everything has technically already been written to the HTML, and I think I might have broken my page temporarily that way (Hit a resource limit on my host)

My main goal is trying to figure out how I can use Javascript to alter elements of my page one by one. Which I figure I could do if I could find the html tags I'm trying to change...which the PHP wrote...in the same page.

Very new to Javascript you see.

Comment: could you please explain what is what you intend to do with Javascript? alter elements one by one? by class? id? which type of elements? This is useful in the sense that Javascript will help you change things on the fly but it can be different depending on what you want to change.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Do you need your PHP script to search through the tags in order to offer some kind of hinting to the JavaScript? Because if you just want to get a good idea of the structure of the document before you write your JavaScript, you could just run the PHP like normal and inspect the output any old way you please.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is figure out how to animate a list. See, the page displays a list (not li format) of posts based on a combination of entries into a text file, imploded. So by the time it's spat out into the HTML, it's a collection of posts made, and separated and colored specificly by their div tags....the static version is working fine, so now what I want to do is animate each post in, and I'm not sure how to target each post to do that. Maybe a foreach equivalent of every div tag inside a master wrapper div tag. I don't even know if I should be using php for that. Not surewhere2 start

Answer (score 1):

You could do this fairly easily, client side, with jquery.

If you absolutely need to process it server side with php and you absolutely can't do it while generating the code, you could use ob_start() to capture the output and then ob_get_contents() to drop it into a string before doing ob_end_clean() to flush it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click on your rendered web page in most browsers and choose some variant of 'View Source'. Or, you can [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) your page's content, and view it as a text file.

Also, `file_get_contents();` makes a new request to get a page / file's contents. So, if you load a page, and at the bottom, it tries to get the page content, it's going to load a new page, then another, forever. You're creating an infinite loop, and exhausting your allocated resources, as dictated by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

if I did not understand wrong, after page is loaded you want to change your own html output so,

```
<?php
 echo "<div id='mydiv'></div>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

      window.onload = function() {  
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "updated html";  
      }  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're capturing the output as you generate the page, e.g.

```
<?php

ob_start();
.... page building here ...
$page = ob_get_clean();
echo $page;
?>
```

there will be NOTHING for you to work on. However, if you are capturing as above, then you can simply feed $page into [DOM](http://php.net/dom) and manipulate it there.

But this begs the question... if you need to change the page after it's been built, why not just change how it's built in the first place?